Enable/Disable Logging block in Vector CANoe through COM
I am trying to Enable/Disable the Logging Block using COM Objects in python. I could access the individual loggings from the collection, but cannot enable them programatically. I tried below way, the Application starts and starts measurement, but no log file is created.
app = client.dynamic.Dispatch('CANoe.Application')
app.Open(configuration)
app.Configuration.OnlineSetup.LoggingCollection(1).Filter.Enable(0)
app.Measurement.Start()
app.Measurement.Stop()
app.Quit()


How can the Logging be enabled/disabled through python?

You have to activate the logging block itself. Based on your code something like this should do:
app.Configuration.OnlineSetup.ActivateEndBlock("Logging", true)


As per documentation, function ActivateEndBlock is not available.

Just checked the documentation: "Available since 16 SP2"

Ok, I am using an older version, so could'nt find it. Thank you.

@lerner1225 The only workaround I could think of is to have the logging block always enabled but disable all events in the logging file configuration. The filtering of events can be changed over COM.
